# Regular Expression to find div with specific class and all content within it

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to find a div with specific class and all content within it.

I tried to use below expression but this did not work.

```
<div class="[^"]*?topbarT0[^"]*?">(.*?)</div>
```

Comment: Can't be done. `<div><div class="topbarT0"><div>hmmm...</div></div></div>`

Comment: i agree that it will not work for nested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is just fine, you might want to add a capturing group, and maybe word boundaries, that I'm guessing:

```
(<div class="[^"]*?\btopbarT0\b[^"]*?">.*?<\/div>)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/9X6DAc/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/9X6DAc/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

---

Looking at your samples though, it seems like really complicated to do that with regular expressions, primarily because of nested elements; maybe it wouldn't be such a bad idea, if you would try to script/code and use an HTML parser.

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/ccQ6Z4/1)

Comment: what if i want to find id instead of class ?

Comment: its mean i cant do it